# Convert this cuRL to CFHTTP - Azure NotificationHub

Tags: php, azure, coldfusion, azure-notificationhub, cfhttp

I'm trying to get push working from a ColdFusion script using the Azure REST API.  There is a working PHP script located [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples/tree/master/notificationhubs-rest-php) and I have tried to convert the PHP to ColdFusion.  Below is the code I have so far, and everything seems to be correct to me, I'm not getting any errors.  However, the result in cfhttp.FileContent is just an empty string and I get no notification.  can anyone point out my mistake?

```
    <cfset CONNECTION_STRING = "Endpoint=sb://mypushnamespacehere.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=mysharedaccesskeyhere">
    <cfset API_VERSION = "?api-version=2015-01">
    <cfset connectionStringParts = ListToArray(CONNECTION_STRING,';','YES')>
    <cfset ENDPOINT = "https" & #connectionStringParts[1].substring(11)#>
    <cfset HUBPATH = "myhubpathname">
    <cfset sasKEYNAME = #connectionStringParts[2].substring(20)#>
    <cfset sasKEYVALUE = #connectionStringParts[3].substring(16)#>

    <cfset URI = #ENDPOINT# & #HUBPATH# & "/messages" & API_VERSION>

    <cfset TARGET_URI = #Lcase(URLEncodedFormat(URI))#>
    <cfset EXPIRES = int(createObject('java', 'java.lang.System').currentTimeMillis()/1000)>
    <cfset EXPIRES_IN_MINS = 60>
    <cfset EXPIRES = EXPIRES + EXPIRES_IN_MINS * 60>

    <cfset TO_SIGN = #TARGET_URI# & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & #EXPIRES#>
    <cfset SIGNATURE_HMAC = #HMAC(TO_SIGN, sasKEYVALUE, 'HmacSHA256')#>
    <cfset SIGNATURE = #EncodeForURL(binaryEncode(binaryDecode(SIGNATURE_HMAC, 'hex'), 'base64'))#>

    <cfset TOKEN = "SharedAccessSignature sr=" & #TARGET_URI# & "&sig=" & #SIGNATURE# & "&se=" & #EXPIRES# & "&skn=" & #sasKEYNAME#>

    <cftry>
        <!--- Create our requestBody --->
        <cfset requestBody = '{
                                "data" : {
                                    "message" : "Hello from ColdFusion"
                                    }
                                }'>
        <!--- Send Push --->
        <cfhttp method="post" url="#URI#">    
            <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="#TOKEN#">
            <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json">    
            <cfhttpparam type="header" name="ServiceBusNotification-Format" value="gcm">
            <cfhttpparam type="body" encoded="false" value="#trim(requestBody)#">
        </cfhttp>   
        <!--- Parse JSON Response to determine if call was successful --->
        <cfdump var=#cfHttp.FileContent#>
    <!--- Catch any errors, return false --->
    <cfcatch type="any">
        <cfdump var=#cfcatch#>
    </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
```

**UPDATE**

I tested using the SIGNATURE that the PHP script generates and it worked from ColdFusion.  So it is something with the way I'm generating the SIGNATURE variable that is not matching up to how PHP generates it.

Here is what PHP does...

```
$targetUri = strtolower(rawurlencode(strtolower($uri)));
$expires = time();
$expiresInMins = 60;
$expires = $expires + $expiresInMins * 60;
$toSign = $targetUri . "\n" . $expires;

$signature = rawurlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $toSign, $this->sasKeyValue, TRUE)));

$token = "SharedAccessSignature sr=" . $targetUri . "&sig=" . $signature . "&se=" . $expires . "&skn=" . $this->sasKeyName;
```

Comment: While debugging it's recommended to remove cftry/cfcatch.

Comment: @AlexBaban, will do however I am doing a <cfdump var=#cfcatch#> in the catch block. so I should still see any error messages

Comment: How about $expires, do you have a match between PHP and ColdFusion?

Comment: @AlexBaban - yep both say 1464886129 when I just ran them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.
In PHP, the "\n" for a newline works fine, but when I was converting it over to ColdFusion I was using Chr(13) & Chr(10).  Took the Chr(13) out and only used Chr(10) and it works great now.

**Updated**

```
<cfset TO_SIGN = TARGET_URI & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & EXPIRES>
```

**to**

```
<cfset TO_SIGN = TARGET_URI & Chr(10) & EXPIRES>
```

Comment: @Leigh - for the record, I REALLY like my pound signs. ;)

Comment: .@Phil, use them then, it's a free country brother.

Comment: @AlexBaban - Leigh took them away when she edited my post :(

Comment: @Phil - Then we must balance each other out, because I really loathe them ;-) Seriously though, there is nothing syntactically wrong with using them, but .. even the Adobe docs recommend NOT using pound signs when they are not needed (as in this case).

Comment: @Phil - It is *your* post, so you are always free to roll back any edits. Just keep in mind the archives are here to serve as a reference for *everyone*. Including folks new to the language. So whenever possible the archives should recommend good style and best practices :)

Comment: @Leigh - it's okay really I was just kidding around.  I've become SO set in my old ways of always using them it's hard to break out.  I appreciate your edits though truly, others will benefit having the code meet the recommendations from Adobe so we'll leave as is.

Comment: @Phil - Heh, phew.  Took me a while to kick the habit too. After starting with some truly dreadful CF legacy apps, it was practically an involuntary response: *See CFML code. Must add pound signs..* ;-)